# Deploy and Compile single Angular Typescript File

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to update my live server but I want to avoid it breaking it. Is it possible I deploy just the single file I have made changes to on my local machine instead of compiling and deploying the whole project.

Comment: I don't think this is possible since the already compiled files won't know that the new file exists...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since when building Angular, the components are assembled in a single js file !

Look at your exisiting build, you will probably see a `main.****.js`, `vendor.***.js` etc.